# Last thread is not being executed in Python 2.7

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a function titled as `move`, which does some time-consuming task. I need to call this function in a separate thread. However, call to the function `move` must be sequential. For example, the next thread should be created only if the previous thread finished.

Below is the sample code:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from threading import Thread
from thread import start_new_thread

class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 10

    def move(self, point):
        print '\nMove ',
        points = []
        i = 1
        while True:
            value = i * point
            points.append(value)
            if len(points) > self.length:
                break
            time.sleep(0.1)#100 ms
            print value,
            i += 1

test = Test()

def move_test():
    points = [3, 5, 7]
    def move_test_thread(points):
        for point in points:
            thread = Thread(target=test.move, args=(point,))
            thread.start()
            thread.join()
    start_new_thread(move_test_thread, (points,))

a = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QWidget()
w.resize(320, 240)
w.setWindowTitle("Hello World!")

move_button = QPushButton('move', w)
move_button.clicked.connect(move_test)
move_button.resize(move_button.sizeHint())
move_button.move(40, 80)

w.show()
sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

The above code prints following output:

```
Move  3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 
Move  5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't execute thread for last point i.e., 7. Why such strange behavior? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: As you describe "call to the function move must be sequential", sounds like it should not be threaded. Your call `start_new_thread(move_test_thread, (points,))` already starts another thread, so starting more "sequential" threads within that new thread does not accomplish anything. Replace your calls to threading in your loop with simple `test.move(point)` and you accomplish the sequential execution in a separate thread (the thread created by start_new_thread). The code (as you wrote it) executes for all three points for me.

Comment: @JohnAnderson: Thank you very much. Let me give you a brief overview of better understanding, function `move_test()` is defined in GUI. The function `move` takes time to respond. Also as you said it should be executed sequentially, which means first it should print series `3 6 9 12 ...` completely, then it should print next series. `start_new_thread` is used to keep the GUI active.

Comment: Yes, the `start_new_thread` will keep the GUI active, so starting additional threads accomplishes nothing.

Comment: @JohnAnderson: Yes, make sense. I removed additional threads inside `for` loop. However, the code still doesn't print series for last point 7. It prints only when I close the application. Other than that, how to terminate the `start_new_thread` while it is running from another function, left say `def stop_test()`?

Comment: You cannot easily stop a thread that is started by `start_new_thread()`, however, if you use the Process class from the multiprocessing package, you can call the terminate() method on the process. Have a look at https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class

Comment: Thank you very much. I am wondering if invoking a` process` may be a bit overkill? I just need a simple `thread`, as the task is not so big.

Comment: I don't know enough to comment on the performance implications, but if you need the capabilities, it is not overkill.